# How can I install an AspNet Core application in a subdirectory?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, deployment, subdirectory

I have setup a web application in IIS. There are no files or anything in it. 
.../wwwroot/automock

Next, in IIS in a subfolder called v1 I setup an aspnetcore web application that points to my publish files in another directory.

I would like my application to be available at:

http://www.[domain].com/v1/

I hope then to be able to deploy multiple versions in different sub-folders.

When, I request the page at http://www.[domain].com/v1 I get 404s for all of my javascript resources.

[image]

How, can I configure my aspnetcore application to serve these files correctly?
If it is IIS related how can I setup IIS to serve the web application properly from a subfolder?

Comment: Set up a site to host ASP.NET Core app, and then use reverse proxying to manipulate the URLs.

Comment: Not sure what reverse proxying is. Sounds like a hack

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy Something commonly used in the industry if you never know.

Comment: I have found that seeting --deploy-url=/v1/ --base-href=/v1/ allows the angular application to work fine but now I need to get my controllers to work again. I just get 404 errors.